# Dart inheritance and super constructor

Tags: inheritance, dart, super

I am trying to define an abstract parent class `Event` and a concrete child `PlaceChangeEvent`:

```
abstract class Event {
    String name;
    DateTime occurredAt;
    int handleCount;

    Event(this.name, this.occurredAt, [this.handleCount = 0]);
}

class PlaceChangeEvent implements Event {
    Place place;

    PlaceChangeEvent(Place place) : super(place.name, DateTime.now());
}
```

The `PlaceChangeEvent` is giving me 2 compiler warnings:

- The first is on the class name itself: `Missing inherited members: 'Event.name', 'Event.handleCount' and 'Event.occurredAt'`
- The second is on the call to `super`: `0 positional arguments expected, but 2 found`

Where did I go wrong and what can I do to fix this? My intentions are to:

- Hardcode the parent's `name` with the `place.name`; and
- Hardcode the parent's `occurredAt` property with the current date/time'; and
- Initialize the parent's optional `handleCount` property to 0 by simply not providing it.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to extend from your `Event` class instead of implementing it:

```
class PlaceChangeEvent extends Event {
```

Implements mean, that your class implements the interface of the class, but not inherits its members, you need to implement them by your self. You get the warning about the super constructor as you still extend from `Object` instead of `Event` and `Object` don't have a constructor with two arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Fox32 (+1) - yes replacing `implements` with `extends` fixed everything, except now its telling me that `DateTime.now()` doesn;t exist. However when I look at the [`DateTime` dart docs](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/DateTime.html) it seems like a valid static call.  Ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: It's not a static method on DateTime, it's a named constructor. (ie: you still need the 'new' keyword before it)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old and provided answer is good, should be accepted. So, here an example on difference between `implements` and `extends`:

```
import 'dart:math';

abstract class Shape {
  num get area;

  @override String toString() => 'Area is ${this.area}';
}

class Square extends Shape {
  final num side;
  Square({this.side: 2});

  num get area => this.side * this.side;
}

class Circle implements Shape {
  final num radius;
  Circle(this.radius);
  num get area => PI * pow(radius, 2);
}

void main() {
  print(new Square());
  print(new Circle(4));
}
```

And when you run it:

```
dart "./dart-tut/shape.dart"
Area is 4
Instance of 'Circle'
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you're implementing your class rather than extending it. Implementation of your class means that your sub-class must provide the corresponding methods. The implementation means that your concrete class should have a getter and setter for those properties (or just define those properties themselves). It won't actually inherit the ones defined in the class because you are not extending the `Event` class

Comment: Thanks @Matt B (+1) - please see my question underneath Fox32's answer - I have the same question for you!