# Dart: inheritance and super constructor

Tags: inheritance, dart, mvp, multiple-inheritance, super

My Dart app has the following class hierarchy:

```dart
abstract class AbstractPresenter {
    AbstractView view;

    AbstractPresenter(this.view);

    void start(EventBus eventBus) {
        view.presenter = this;
        querySelector("body").innerHTML = view.render();
    }
}

abstract class SigninPresenter implements AbstractPresenter {
    void onSignin(MouseEvent mouseEvent);
}

class DefaultSigninPresenter implements SigninPresenter {
    // Lots of code
}

abstract class AbstractView {
    AbstractPresenter presenter;

    AbstractView(this.presenter);

    String render();

    void bindUI(String html);
}

abstract class SigninView implements AbstractView {
    SigninView(AbstractPresenter presenter) : super(presenter);

    LabelElement getSigninLabel();

    void setSigninLabel(LabelElement signinLabel);

    InputElement getEmailTextField();

    void setEmailTextField(InputElement emailTextField);
}

class DefaultSigninView implements SigninView {
    LabelElement signinLabel;
    InputElement emailTextField;

    DefaultSigninView(SigninPresenter presenter) : super(presenter);

    // Lots of code...
}
```

The idea is to define a hierarchy of "views" and "presenters", where ultimately a `DefaultSigninView` will get related (bidirectionally) to a `DefaultSigninPresenter`.

But I'm getting a compiler warning in `DefaultSigninView`'s constructor, complaining about my call to `super(presenter)`:

> Missing inherited member 'AbstractView.presenter'

Why can't it "see" the presenter I'm passing it? The parent constructor (`AbstractView`) takes an `AbstractPresenter`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because SigninView has not implemented all of the members of AbstractView. The same situation as your question here: [Dart inheritance and super constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859472/dart-inheritance-and-super-constructor)

You are not extending AbstractView but implementing it. This means that you must implement a getter/setter for an `AbstractPresenter presenter`. Properties are not inherited if you only implement the class.

From the [Dart language spec](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.pk4aq5ol5027):

> A class does not inherit members from its superinterfaces.

Comment: Thanks @Matt B (+1) - however if I change `abstract class SigninView extends AbstractView` to `abstract class SigninView implements AbstractView` I get a new error altogether: "*0 positional arguments expected, but 1 found*". Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: My guess is that you call something with one argument, although it doesn't take one. (Could be a super-constructor call, or a static function).